# How to send a zip file to frontend to download in DRF

Tags: python, django, download, zip, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send a zip file to frontend so that it could download it in the browser.

Zip file has a folders inside and those folders have files:

```
file.zip
    - first folder
      - file1.pdf
      - file2.pdf
    - second folder
      - file3.pdf
```

I think that I need to convert the file to bytes first to send it as a response so I tried to do this:

```
zip_file = ZipFile(zip_file_path)

zip_byte_array = bytearray()
for filename in zip_file.namelist():
    byte_content = zip_file.read(filename)
    zip_byte_array.append(byte_content)

return Response(zip_byte_array)
```

It gives the following error while appending to the bytearray:

```
an integer is required
```

the folder was archived like this:

```
zip_file_path = shutil.make_archive(dir_path, 'zip', dir_path)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, it turns out it is a little easier than I thought. I could easily do this:

```
zip_file = open(zip_file_path, 'rb')

response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=name.zip'

return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending a byte array is assumed to be executed with an integer that will have the value of the appended byte, since `append` is mostly comprehended as an operation of adding an item to an array, and `bytearray` is a numerical sequence.

For arrays concatenation, just use the `+` operator, like strings:

```
zip_byte_array += byte_content
```